# Patch newline (\\) in math environment using amsmath

Tags: macros, amsmath, align

I want to patch the newline command \\ in an align environment provided by amsmath. The patched version should execute some custom code and finally call the original definition, like in the following example.

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
    \begin{align}
        \let\old\\%
        \def\\{1\old}%
        %
        a\\
        b\\
        c
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

This results in:
[image]

So it works only for the first call (the "b" is missing a "1"). Why is this and how can I make it work for all newlines?

Comment: `align` uses the same mechanism as `tabular` and all cells are implicit groups, so that a local definition doesn't survive the cell in which it's given. Can you please give more motivation for what you're trying to do?

Comment: @egreg: In the end, I want to prepend a \notag command to the newline if the line has not been referenced. The idea is to extend the autonum package to more advanced environments (as align).

Comment: Adding `\global` before the `\let` and the `\def` does not solve the problem. Then an error about the exceeded memory capacity of TeX is thrown. I was just guessing anyways ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although the ideas in Mico's comment probably do work, they would be very specific to one environment and subject to break if anything related changes. I was heading for a more general solution.

There are two problems:

1. As egreg points out, every line is an implicit group, so that all local definitions get deleted before the next line.
2. Every amsmath environment is executed twice, first for measuring its size and then for printing.

Because of 1., `\global` has to be used. Because of 2., every direct `\let` followed by a `\def` of the same command will lead to an infinite recursion in the second pass, because the `\let` then points to itself, so the \gdef reaches towards an infity.

With this knowledge, a fix is simple. The recursion has to be avoided by only executing the commands in the first pass. Thus, this is solution:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\begin{document}
    \begin{align}
        \ifundef{\old}{%
            \global\let\old\\%
            \gdef\\{1\old}%
        }{}
        %
        a\\
        b\\
        c
    \end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image: result]

Comment: The drawback of this method is, one cannot make use of ```\\``` outside `tabular` environments in text mode (okay, probably not advised) since, at the end of `align` environment, ```\\``` is globally redefined as the default one **inside `align` environment**, which is not the same as the ``real'' default one. As a workaround, it is enough to ```\global\let\originaldblbackslash\\``` before the 1st patch (e.g. in the preamble) and to ```\global\let\\\originaldblbackslash``` after the end of `align`. That's what I did in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/397638/18401.

Comment: This also only works for a single align environment, because `old` will be defined the second time around. You need to add `\global\undef\old` at the end to reset it.

Answer (score 1):

You mention in a comment that your goal is to automatically affix a `\notag` instruction to all equations that aren't cross-referenced in the document. To achieve this objective, you could load the [mathtools](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/mh) package and issue the command

```
\mathtoolsset{showonlyrefs}
```

in the preamble.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. What I did not state in my question was that I exactly want to overcome some deficiencies of the mathtools package in that regard. So I am really interested in some information or tip about how to patch the newline in an align environment.

Comment: @MMM -- Take a look at the file `amsmath.sty` (if you haven't already done so). There are lots and lots of definitions of the form `\math@cr`, `\math@cr@`, `\math@cr@@`, `\math@cr@@@`, etc., and the various amsmath equation-related environments make use of these macros rather than of `\\` directly. (A reason for this, I surmise, is that `amsmath` measures the width of any equation line first before typesetting it, so as to decide whether the associated equation number should be set next to or below the equation.) You'll probably need to change these macros to achieve your goal.