# Add a marginal note when a page break occurs in the middle of a multi-line equation

Tags: align, environments, page-breaking, displaybreak

Thanks to the `amsmath`'s `\allowdisplaybreaks` macro, it is possible to let page breaks fall where they may, even in the middle of multi-line equations (from e.g. the `align` environment).

- **Advantage of `\allowdisplaybreaks`:** otherwise (prohibiting page breaks in the middle of multi-line equations), the document is likely to contain very ugly underfull vboxes.
- **Drawback of `\allowdisplaybreaks`:** "we haven't a view on all the equation in this case", as said in [Allow displaybreak only from even to odd pages](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/224020/18401).

In order to reduce the above drawback, a solution could be to add a marginal note (containing something like "eq. follows next page") when a page break occurs in a multi-line equation.

Is it possible to achieve such a result, e.g. for the `align` environment?

### Edit

Here is a MWE of what I'd like to achieve, easily obtained by hand but that I'd like obtained automatically. It contains a footnote and a floating figure in order to point out that a marginal note located at the bottom (right) of the page wouldn't be enough since it could be far from the line where the equation is broken.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{marginnote}
\usepackage[papersize={130mm,140mm},margin=30mm]{geometry}

\allowdisplaybreaks

\newcommand{\eqcont}{\tiny(Cont.\ next page)}

\begin{document}
Foo\footnote{\tiny\lipsum[1]}
\begin{multline}
  x = abcdefghijklmopqrstuvwyz                    \\
   + abcdefghijklmopqrstuvwyz                     \\
   + abcdefghijklmopqrstuvwyz                     \\
   + abcdefghijklmopqrstuvwyz                     \\
   + abcdefghijklmopqrstuvwyz                     \\
   + abcdefghijklmopqrstuvwyz                     \\
   + abcdefghijklmopqrstuvwyz\marginnote{\eqcont} \\
   + abcdefghijklmopqrstuvwyz                     \\
   + abcdefghijklmopqrstuvwyz                     \\
   + abcdefghijklmopqrstuvwyz
\end{multline}

\begin{figure}[b]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[height=1cm]{image-a}
    \caption{A nice figure}
    \label{nice-figure}
\end{figure}

\begin{align}
  1 + 1 & = 2                     \\
  2 + 1 & = 3                     \\
  3 + 1 & = 4                     \\
  4 + 1 & = 5                     \\
  5 + 1 & = 6                     \\
  6 + 1 & = 7\marginnote{\eqcont} \\
  7 + 1 & = 8                     \\
  8 + 1 & = 9                     \\
  9 + 1 & = 10
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: you can set  a \label on the first and last equation and then (with a bit of care or using ifthenelse which takes care for you) compare the pageref of the two labels and do something if they are not the same...

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Does this trick work with non numbered equations (`align*` environment?). And could this trick be automatized (the document contains a lot of `align(*)` environments)?

Comment: It doesn't matter if the equations are numbered or not, as you are comparing \pageref.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Unfortunately, this wouldn't work for a `multline` equation where at most one `\label` may be inserted.

Comment: details:-), you don't really need an equation number or real `\label` you  can just use some internal version  of `\label` `multline` doesn't know about, so long as you can write two things to the aux file and check if they are the same or different.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle If I understand well, I would have to patch the `\\ ` macro in order to app to it a "some internal" `\label`, with an automatically incremented argument, which would write the current pageref to  the `.aux` and, afterwards, the `.aux` file would have to be read in order to add a marginal note to the previous line if its label differs from the one of the current line.  Well, details... for you! :)  Could you elaborate?

Comment: possibly later or some else may take that hint and make an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I managed, with the hope I didn't forget possible side effects. The following MWE contains comments explaining the approach (later, I'll try to give the `expl3` flavor of it).

### Edit

My original code gave an error when the `\\` was used in text mode outside `tabular` environments since, at the end of the multi-line equation environments, `\\` was globally redefined as the one inside these environments, which is not the same as the default one.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{refcount}
\usepackage{xifthen}
\usepackage{marginnote}
\usepackage[papersize={130mm,140mm},margin=30mm]{geometry}

\allowdisplaybreaks

\newcommand{\eqcont}{\tiny(Cont.\ next page)}

% Each multiline equation will have a unique number.
\newcounter{multilineeq}
% Each line of a multiline equation will have a unique number (local
% to the multiline equation).
\newcounter{lineofmultilineeq}[multilineeq]

\makeatletter
% We globally store the original double backslash in a macro
\global\let\original@double@backslash\\
% We define the patched macro of the double backslash one
\newcommand{\patched@double@backslash}{%
  % We increment the counter of the current line.
  \stepcounter{lineofmultilineeq}%
  % We set the label of the current line.
  \ltx@label{\lineofmultilineeq@label}%
  % If (and only if) the pageref of the next line if greater than the
  % current line's one, we insert a marginal note telling the equation
  % continues on next page.
  \ifthenelse{%
    \cnttest{%
      \getpagerefnumber{\nextlineofmultilineeq@label}%
    }{>}{%
      \getpagerefnumber{\lineofmultilineeq@label}%
    }%
  }{%
    \marginnote{\eqcont}%
  }{}
  % We break the line with the original double backslash macro.
  \original@local@double@backslash%
}
% We define a hack to be applied at the beginning of each multiline equation
% environment (currently, only `align(*)' and `multline(*)').
\def\beginhack{%
  % We set the unique number that has the current multiline equation.
  \stepcounter{multilineeq}
  % The number that has the 1st line of the current multiline equation is 1.
  \stepcounter{lineofmultilineeq}
  % We globally define the strings of the labels identfying:
  % - the current line,
  % - the line following the current one,
  % of the current multiline equation.
  \gdef\lineofmultilineeq@label{multilineeq-\themultilineeq-line-\thelineofmultilineeq}
  \gdef\nextlineofmultilineeq@label{multilineeq-\themultilineeq-line-\the\numexpr\thelineofmultilineeq+1}
  % We set the label of the current line.
  \ltx@label{\lineofmultilineeq@label}
  % Within the current multiline equation, we patch the double backslash macro
  % (for more details, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/59117/18401).
  \ifundef{\original@local@double@backslash}{%
    \global\let\original@local@double@backslash\\%
    \global\let\\\patched@double@backslash%
  }{}
}
% We define a hack to be applied at the end of each multiline equation
% environment (currently, only `align(*)' and `multline(*)').
\def\endhack{%
  % We globally unpatch the double backslash macro
  \global\let\\\original@double@backslash%
  \global\undef\original@local@double@backslash
}
\makeatother

\appto\align{\beginhack}
\csappto{align*}{\beginhack}
\appto\endalign{\endhack}
%
\appto\multline{\beginhack}
\csappto{multline*}{\beginhack}
\appto\endmultline{\endhack}

\begin{document}
Foo\footnote{\tiny\lipsum[1]}
\begin{multline}
  x = abcdefghijklmopqrstuvwyz \\
   + abcdefghijklmopqrstuvwyz  \\[1cm]
   + abcdefghijklmopqrstuvwyz  \\
   + abcdefghijklmopqrstuvwyz  \\
   + abcdefghijklmopqrstuvwyz  \\
   + abcdefghijklmopqrstuvwyz  \\
   + abcdefghijklmopqrstuvwyz  \\
   + abcdefghijklmopqrstuvwyz  \\
   + abcdefghijklmopqrstuvwyz  \\
   + abcdefghijklmopqrstuvwyz  \\
   + abcdefghijklmopqrstuvwyz  \\
   + abcdefghijklmopqrstuvwyz  \\
   + abcdefghijklmopqrstuvwyz  \\
   + abcdefghijklmopqrstuvwyz  \\
   + abcdefghijklmopqrstuvwyz  \\
   + abcdefghijklmopqrstuvwyz  \\
   + abcdefghijklmopqrstuvwyz  \\
   + abcdefghijklmopqrstuvwyz  \\
   + abcdefghijklmopqrstuvwyz  \\
   + abcdefghijklmopqrstuvwyz  \\
   + abcdefghijklmopqrstuvwyz  \\
   + abcdefghijklmopqrstuvwyz  \\
   + abcdefghijklmopqrstuvwyz  \\
   + abcdefghijklmopqrstuvwyz  \\
   + abcdefghijklmopqrstuvwyz  \\
   + abcdefghijklmopqrstuvwyz  \\
   + abcdefghijklmopqrstuvwyz  \\
   + abcdefghijklmopqrstuvwyz  \\
   + abcdefghijklmopqrstuvwyz  \\
   + abcdefghijklmopqrstuvwyz  \\
   + abcdefghijklmopqrstuvwyz  \\
   + abcdefghijklmopqrstuvwyz  \\
   + abcdefghijklmopqrstuvwyz  \\
   + abcdefghijklmopqrstuvwyz  \\
   + abcdefghijklmopqrstuvwyz  \\
   + abcdefghijklmopqrstuvwyz  \\
   + abcdefghijklmopqrstuvwyz  \\
   + abcdefghijklmopqrstuvwyz  \\
   + abcdefghijklmopqrstuvwyz  \\
   + abcdefghijklmopqrstuvwyz  \\
   + abcdefghijklmopqrstuvwyz  \\
   + abcdefghijklmopqrstuvwyz
\end{multline}

Foo\\Bar.

\begin{tabular}{l}
Foo\\Bar.
\end{tabular}

\begin{figure}[b]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[height=1cm]{example-image-a}
  \caption{A nice figure}
  \label{nice-figure}
\end{figure}

\begin{align}
  1 + 1 & = 2 \\
  2 + 1 & = 3 \\
  3 + 1 & = 4 \\
  4 + 1 & = 5 \\
  5 + 1 & = 6 \\
  6 + 1 & = 7 \\
  7 + 1 & = 8 \\
  8 + 1 & = 9 \\
  1 + 1 & = 2 \\
  2 + 1 & = 3 \\
  3 + 1 & = 4 \\
  4 + 1 & = 5 \\
  5 + 1 & = 6 \\
  6 + 1 & = 7 \\
  7 + 1 & = 8 \\
  8 + 1 & = 9 \\
  1 + 1 & = 2 \\
  2 + 1 & = 3 \\
  3 + 1 & = 4 \\
  4 + 1 & = 5 \\
  5 + 1 & = 6 \\
  6 + 1 & = 7 \\
  7 + 1 & = 8 \\
  8 + 1 & = 9 \\
  1 + 1 & = 2 \\
  2 + 1 & = 3 \\
  3 + 1 & = 4 \\
  4 + 1 & = 5 \\
  5 + 1 & = 6 \\
  6 + 1 & = 7 \\
  7 + 1 & = 8 \\
  8 + 1 & = 9 \\
  9 + 1 & = 10
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps something like this:

[image]

I have used `\appto` (and `\csappto`) hooks from the [etoolbox](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) to set and unset a boolean flag, `ifInAlign`, in the `align` and `align*` environments (other environments can be done in exactly the same way). The idea is that `\ifInAlign` is true when you are inside an `align` environment and false otherwise. Then, using the [background](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/background) package I add "background text" to each page that is given by

```
\ifInAlign\tiny Equation continues...\fi
```

That is, we see `Equation continues...` when the `Align` environment extends across the page and otherwise we see nothing.

Here is the full code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[papersize={100mm,80mm}, margin=20mm]{geometry}% to get short pages

\newif\ifInAlign\InAlignfalse% to determine if we're inside an align environment

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\appto\align{\global\InAligntrue}% InAlign true at start of align
\csappto{align*}{\global\InAligntrue}% InAlign true at start of align*
\appto\endalign{\global\InAlignfalse}% InAlign false at end

\usepackage{background}% add continued note when InAlign
\backgroundsetup{angle=0,
  scale=1,
  color=black,
  position={0.68\textwidth,-0.95\textheight},
  contents={\ifInAlign\tiny Equation continues...\fi}
}

\everymath{\allowdisplaybreaks[4]}% turn on display breaks, always!
\begin{document}

  \begin{align}
      0 + 1 &= 1\\% some deep multi-lined aligned equations
      1 + 1 &= 2\\
      2 + 1 &= 3\\
      3 + 1 &= 4\\
      4 + 1 &= 5\\
      5 + 1 &= 6\\
      6 + 1 &= 7\\
      7 + 1 &= 8\\
      8 + 1 &= 9\\
      9 + 1 &= 10\\
      10 + 1 &= 11\\
      11 + 1 &= 12\\
      12 + 1 &= 13\\
      13 + 1 &= 14\\
      14 + 1 &= 15\\
      15 + 1 &= 16\\
      16 + 1 &= 17\\
      17 + 1 &= 18\\
      18 + 1 &= 19\\
      19 + 1 &= 20
  \end{align}

\end{document}
```

To guarantee that the equation breaks across pages I used the [geometry](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/) package to make the page size quite small.

Comment: Using the `background` package to perform a (conditional) action at each page is a very nice idea! Would be even better if the text could be located where would be an (outer) marginal note on the last line of the page: maybe not a big deal thanks to the `tikzpagenodes` package (and, in such a case, maybe could be enough to use the `everypage` package loaded by `background`: I'll have a look).

Comment: I meant "right" and not "outer" margin.

Comment: In fact this trick is not as satisfactory as expected: if the page where the break occurs contains a (possibly long) footnote, the wording "Equation continues..." would be far from the line where the equation is broken. A better solution would be to be able to put the wording as a real marginal note in front of the line where the break occurs.

Comment: @DenisBitouzé So you're saying that if there is a long foot note then the message is in the wrong place... Not sure how to adjust for this. Before using the [background](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/background) package I did actually try to use the shipout commands from [atbegshi](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/atbegshi) to place a marginal note but for reasons not clear to me the note always appeared on the wrong page.

Comment: If I'm right, having the message at the right vertical place in the margin needs, not a global flag telling if we are or not in an `align` environment, but a more accurate flag telling, for each line (except the 1st one) within such an environment, if it is or not on the same page as the previous line. If not, a `\marginpar` (or a `marginnote`'s `\marginnote`) should be to emitted just before the  `` \\ `` of this previous line.

Comment: @DenisBitouzé Footnotes were, of course, not mentioned at all in the original question, so this is a bit of changing ballpark. Please post a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) for the new problem.

Comment: Footnotes are not involved at all :) And marginal notes were mentioned in the original question. I'll add a MWE to the question.

Comment: Sorry, previous comment too quickly written: I meant footnotes are an example of what may happen. Another example is floating table or figure at the bottom of the page.